# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file "/mytextfile.txt"' in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

List mytext = new List();

mytext= File.ReadAllLines(@"mytextfile.txt").ToList();

I have a file mytextfile.txt, and i put it in the folder of project. Then I tried to read this file, but i get error and it cant find my file

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file "/mytextfile.txt"

Comment: iOS or Android?  What is the "Build Action" of the file set to?

Comment: Android, Embedded Resource

Comment: an EmbeddedResource is not a file.  If you want to do this on Android, you should use an Android asset

Comment: i get the same error :(

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: its xamarin android, i work with xamarin forms

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT  finally if find this code , and its work

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT                         
                        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(@"Ctg.myfile.txt");                        
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                mylist.Add(line);

Comment: This is similar to the following answer.

Answer (score 1):

`"/mytextfile.txt"` this means that the file will be read from the current directory of the executable. Copy the file to your outdir. It will be able to find it. Or else give a complete physical path e.g `"D:\sample\xamarinapp"`

Comment: i copy the file in assets folder, if its wrong. where should i put the file?

Comment: Keep the file in assets folder only if u want to. Then you can make it to be copied to output always by right clicking on the file and select "Copy Always" in the properties option

Comment: Another way is to add a copy command in the Pre-Build event in your project properties to copy the file to $(OutDir) i.e. the output folder

Comment: i do that, Copy Always , but its not work . i get that error again

Answer (score 0):

The `System.IO` classes can be used to access the file system on each platform.

So if you want to use `File.ReadAllLines` ,it will access your file system of your device,not the `Assets` folder.

You could try to move your `mytextfile.txt` to your PCL project,and set its `Build Action` to `EmbeddedResource`.

And then access it like:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("your namespace.mytextfile.txt");
        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
         {
           text = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
   }
}
```

The more you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows).